# Which cooking apparatus is best to make Croque Monsieur?

Tags: cookware

I'm looking for a small cooking apparatus that I can use to make Croque Monsieur.  I've used this kind of device before but I don't know which words to use to google for it.  Here's how I made a Croque Monsieur from the past:

1. Place a slice of cheese and ham between two bread slices
2. The sandwich is placed in between two grills which press against it like a jaw
3. After a few minutes, parallel grilled marks are left on both sides of the sandwich

Think of the above machine as a closed book engulfing a sandwich.  What's the English name of that machine and is it available in small size(my kitchen has limited space).

Comment: You could just pop it under the grill in your oven. Of course, true Croque Monsiuer is dipped in egg and fried in a pan with butter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The device is called a "panini press" and they're available fairly small.  I've seen ones which aren't much larger than a toaster.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for a "sandwich press", does it look like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Cuisinart-GR-1-Griddler-Panini-Sandwich/dp/B000CPZXGO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CPZXGO) ? Or perhaps [like this](http://www.google.com/search?q=sandwich%20press&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=DXZ&rls=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=xyGJTpfuPI_H0AH83MkP&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CCQQ_AUoAQ&biw=1024&bih=603).

Answer (score 1):

While as BobMcGee [says](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/18149/4580) a panini press gives you the apparatus you were thinking of, I would like to add that there is an apparatus especially for making croques. An old one looks like [this](https://encrypted-tbn1.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsgjlv98oyGOOuEmrmx0ooegrWGdKAiN9L2zZhs1wnQR9GNWJ_VQ), a newer version like [this](https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1NQLRymjUpmsn_BzkMI1UUprWAdPYYCgN0L10orHBpo2idSf_).

I googled 'croque monsieur machine' to get the results, it's the term we use here (Belgium). It's fairly cheap and is about as large as a waffle iron.

Answer (score 0):

My only comment on this is that I've never had a croque in france cooked on a panini press.

The authentic ones are always sautéed. Personally I make them by buttering the outside of the bread, and shoving the sandwich into a cast-iron skillet. Don't need to press on the top either - that leads to it being more like a panini which I find is compressed - the french croque isn't.

Basically, it's a fried cheese and ham sarni - not a grilled panini.

Comment: Nitpicking maybe, but you don't sautee a sandwich. It would involve chopping it and keeping the pieces in motion in the pan.

Comment: I do chop up a loaf (slice the bread) and then keep it in motion in the pan. That results in an even brown toasting of the bread rather than hotspots, etc. :)